# How can I decouple consumers from configuring queues in rabbitpy

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I'd like to create exchanges and queues in the RabbitMQ server. 
In the consumer, however, I do not want it explicitly declare a queue and receive messages from there. Is there a way to receive queue configuration from the server once a connection/channel is established? (maybe something like `q_config = conn.get_q_config(qname)`) and then declare the queue using `rabbitpy.Queue(qname, durable=q_config['durable'])...`

Similarly for the publisher. Simply don't declare any config for exchanges. Use only exchange  names to publish.

(btw, I am using rabbitpy because they claim to be thread-safe)